# noAck parameter is not working in NestJS RabbitMQ microservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs, consumer

I'm using [ServerRMQ](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/server/server-rmq.ts) strategy to build microservice in the NestJS application. 
I've set `noAck` field to false in the server options:

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(ApplicationModule, {
  strategy: new ServerRMQ({
    urls: [RABBITMQ_URI],
    queue: EXAMPLE_QUEUE_NAME,
    noAck: false,
    queueOptions: {durable: false},
  }),
});

await app.listenAsync();
```

When an error occurs during event handling I'm calling `channel.nack` method to send `not acknowledge` message to RMQ. After that RMQ should resend the message:

```
@EventPattern(ExampleMessagePattern.EVENT)
  handleExampleEvent(
    @Payload() {meta, payload}: IExampleEventData,
    @Ctx() context: RmqContext,
  ) {
    try{
      ...    // Performing some actions
    } catch(err) {
      const message = context.getMesssage();
      const channel = context.getChannelRef();
      channel.nack(message, false, true);
      // or: context.args[1].nack(context.args[0], false, true);
    }
  }
```

ER: application creates a consumer with `Acknowledgement required` feature enabled, and `nack` method could be successfully called on `channel` object to perform a retry mechanism when an error occurred.

AR: a consumer is created without acknowledgment feature; `channel.nack` method call causes an error on RMQ side and service disconnected from the RMQ server.

Error from RabbitMQ stdout:

> Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1

I have an assumption that `noAck` field does not enable `acknowledgement` feature. To check this I've run a python script using `pika` library and created a consumer with `auto_ack` field set to false:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('rabbit', 'rabbit')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='example')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)


channel.basic_consume(
    queue='example', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=False)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

This script created a consumer that has `ack` feature enabled:

[image]

On the screenshot, you could see consumers list in `RabbitMQ Management UI`. The first one is the python script consumer and is has `Ack required` set to true. The second one is the NestJS ServerRMQ consumer with `noAck` set to false (but `ack` feature does not enable).
I've got the same result when I tried to set `noAck` to true (which is the default behavior in `ServerRMQ`).

Does anyone has faced that kind of problem before? Is it related to NestJS `ServerRMQ` implementation, or I've missed something?

Comment: Funny enough, [there is a pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/3210) to fix this functionality. I would bet it will be part of a minor update soon, or when Nest moves to v7

Comment: Oh, thanks! I've reviewed all PRs, but must be missed that one.

Comment: But I think this issue is not related to the actual problem. I'm creating the configuration using `new ServerRMQ` object, and it already has `noAck` field which is not working properly.

Comment: No actually it is related , since the real issue is noAck does not take the value true under any case , the PR adds the noAck to the interface packages/common/interfaces/microservices/microservice-configuration.interface.ts

Comment: OK, I'll post an update after the PR is merged into the master branch.

Comment: Same here, I've enabled ```noAck``` both sides, but rabbit shows messages as unack in the queue. every time i restart microservice it prints out those messages.